# How to add the recyclerview to project

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

tried to import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView, but it didn't work, added also

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

to build.gradle, but it didn't help either

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file and the error

Comment: post also and layout

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can also add lib/dependencies from android studio menu.

click on "**Build**" ->  "**Edit Libraries and Dependencies**".
then click on "**+**" button on right side.

search any lib.

example search "recycler"

then select "**com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:x.x.x**" from list and your done.

Comment: This is the best answer but still not perfect. The search produces loads of various libraries, but not recycler you need; it can show the latest version, and not the one you need; It might be worth perfecting the answer as it seems quite useful.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open build.gradle and add recycler view dependency. com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 and rebuild the project.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'}
```

2. With the latest version of build tools, Android Studio is creating two layout files for each activity. For main activity, it created activity_main.xml (contains CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout) and content_main.xml (for the actual content). Open content_main.xml and the recycler view widget.

Layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**build gradle:**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

**xml file:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update this Dependency Latest**

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Only putting this

```
implementation'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1.Open build.gradle and add recycler view dependency. 

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1' 

2. left corner of this file sync now option and click on it.

3. in xml file you can add below code:

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/listing"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```