# Failed to import a Recyclerview to my Project

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have tried to import Recyclerview dependency to my project in Android Studio.  But it keep failed.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?  I have attached the gradle file down below.  Thank you!

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: @MahdiEsmaili add a dependency yourself, check my answer

Comment: @MahdiEsmaili You don't need to add the dependencies like that in your `Build.Gradle`. That's a way for not submited libaries in servers/jcenter. Check my answer.

Comment: Do not add at all for several days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use the latest dependencies in your `Build.gradle`. No need for :

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
```

Just add it like this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Then you can delete the file in `libs/` folder.
Other versions :

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

You'll need to be online in order to download the files and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency at `gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Or, you can also add lib/dependencies from android studio menu.

click on "**Build**" ->  "**Edit Libraries and Dependencies**".
then click on "**+**" button on right side.

search any lib.

example search "recycler"

then select "**com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:x.x.x**" from list and your done.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612348/how-to-add-the-recyclerview-to-project).